# Is it possible to record mobile screen using J2ME on symbian device?

Tags: java, java-me

i am doing an project on streaming remote mobile screen to another phone over bluetooth.
Its like application on mobile phone will continuously capture the screen and send it to same application running on other device.The screen will be refreshed on every file received to give a simulation of video file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - unless you target some specific device with vendor-specific API.

None of currently finalized Java ME [JSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Specification_Request)s has an API for that.

Comment: thanks.
in Symbian C++ for 3rd edition...i think it is possible.
screenCapture method is there in its SDK.
anyone have knowledge about it?

Comment: Symbian, I see. Well that would make a different question, wouldn't it. **Is it possible to record mobile screen using Symbian Java ME?** stuff like that

Comment: Symbian makes it whole different from generic Java ME

Comment: Ok Then.Question is "Is it possible to record mobile screen using Symbian Java ME? "

Comment: **DirectGraphics API**....[link] (http://www.j2megame.org/j2meapi/Nokia_UI_API_1_1/com/nokia/mid/ui/DirectGraphics.html)
is it useful...to capture screen pixel.

Comment: @rajesh_kw the Nokia API link you provided doesn't clarify how one could apply it to cases when `Graphics` object is not available for MIDlet developer - ie all the so-called "high level UI" - `Form, List and other subclasses of [lcdui.Screen](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Screen.html)